# How to decode and inspect an HTTP payload when it is a zip

Tags: ajax, http, post, http-post

So I'm pretty new at all this. I am trying to reverse engineer a web application.

When I submit a form, it sends a POST with a request payload that looks something similar to this:

`encoding=UTF8&zip=1&size=136240&html=DwQgIg_a_whole_lot_more_gibberish_not_worth_posting`

Anyways, from inspecting the captured traffic from Chrome developer tools, I noticed it is encoded and sent as a zipped up html?
How would I go about reversing this to see what the content is actually being sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

1) Get the name of the zip file
 2) Get the path of the zip file (likely the root directory or the current path the form is at)
 3) Generate the URL (http://site_name.com/path/to/folder/zip_file.zip)
 4) Download it using a too such as wget (typing the URL into the browser may work too)

I used this technique to download all the files that get downloaded to the OTA updates on iOS devices (used burp suit to intercept the zip file name where the server was on my computer which my iDevice was connected to).

Please note: the name of the zip file you have given does not end in `.zip`. this may mean it doesn't have a extension; you may have to add `.zip` to the file manually; or it may have another ending such as `.tar`, `.tar.gz` etc.